# Problems with app name from ITunes Connect, trying to use same name from deleted app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I have created a app on ITunes connect and it was Pending upload, I deleted that for some reason and tried to create again with the same name and it is saying it is already been used, what is going on??

is itunes connect that stupid or am I missing somthing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email Apple for this manner. they will reset for you. explain what your problem is and the app you deleted.

For future reference, don't delete your app if you want to use back the name. simply rename you unwanted app call StackApp_Old. then you can use back StackApp, next you may delete StackApp_Old.

Comment: that's so apple.... I couldn't figure that I would not be able to use the same name from deleted one... well I can't wait, better change the name, I'm embarrassed for them... thank you very much